# Is it possible to get multiple values from a list and store them into two different lists with one iteration in one line?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value-store

I am trying to figure out if you can to unpack a set of values from a list or a `dict.values()` into multiple different lists in one line is that possible? Suppose my dictionary has a format like this `{key : [x,y]}` that means that the field of values is a list.

For example, I know I can do this:

```
list1 = [ i[1] for i in dict.values()]
```

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
list1,list2 = [i[0],i[1] for i in dict.values()]
```

And store the one value to `list1` and the other to `list2`

Is this even possible to happen? I like it as an idea, short and elegant one iteration done.

P.S. I know how to do it with multiple lines for loop but I am just curious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
d = {1: [1, 2], 3: [4, 67]}

list_1, list_2 = zip(*d.values())
```

to get

`(1, 4)` for `list_1` and `(2, 67)` for `list_2`. But they are tuples; if you want lists, then `map` so:

```py
list_1, list_2 = map(list, zip(*d.values()))
```

`*d.values()` unpacks the values of your dictionary which are lists. Then `zip` takes one element from each list in a parallel fashion to give you the tuples.

Comment: Thanks, @Mustafa Aydin for your answer! I'm gone try it out right now :) cheers mate!

Comment: Add what if you want only a subset of values from each list for example d = {1: [1, 2,3], 3: [4, 67,77]} and I want to get [1,4] and [3,77]?

Comment: @TassosK You can still use the same code, but then it will give you back 3 lists. In your example, you can do `list_1, _, list_3 = map(...)` and you have them. But if you want it generic, then `lists = list(map(...))` and then take the subset as you wish e.g. `list_5 = lists[4]` and `list_10 = lists[9]`. In this latter generic subset case, one line is not possible, i think.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mustafa Aydin! That was exactly what I thought! Peace out bro!